# ggplot2 Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Tags: r

I am creating a plot, when I run it in the console it works but when I try to knit to pdf I get an error message. The variable month is already a variable of class Date.

```
ggplot(data = cars4 %>%
  filter(Brand %in% c("All")), mapping = aes(x = Month, y = tickets, colour = Location)) + 
       geom_line() + geom_point() + 
    scale_y_continuous(name="Total tickets") + 
    labs(title = "Total numbers of tickets") + 
    scale_x_date(name = "Time", date_labels = "%Y", date_breaks = "1 year")
```

> Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Comment: your `x` is the `Month`  column. Are they just plain numbers? or are they proper dates? scale_x_date seems to weant them to be.

Comment: they're in the form %Y-%m-%d @Sirius

Comment: can you tell what data type they are? class( cars4$Month ) . if they aren't one or both of POSIXct or POSIXt, then you could try x = as.Date( Month )

Comment: I get back [1] "Date" when I do class(cars4$Month) @Sirius

Comment: try some of the examples of the manual page of `?scale_x_date` and see if you can make them work. If they work,  then just change things bit by bit until you see what part of your code causes the breakage